# Why do I get so many unresolved symbol compile errors when trying to build from git?

Tags: android, build

For example, I've checked out the froyo-release branch of Gallery. I imported it as a new project targeting Android 2.2 SDK.

I'm getting the following compile errors (among others):

The import android.provider.DrmStore cannot be resolved

The import import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever cannot be resolved

From what I can tell, neither of these classes are in the SDK? Where are they? Should I be including other jars?

Comment: I removed the git tag, since this doesn't have anything to do with git; that just happens to be the VCS used by Android.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you generally cannot build applications that are packaged with the android platform except as part of / on top of a full platform build, unless you do a *lot* of hackery, precisely because they use a lot of capabilities not present in the SDK.  Some of this is due to the unique powers available to system APK's and some apparently due to these apps having originally been developed before the SDK in its present API design was mature enough to target.

Comment: Thanks Chris. But if the app is using these objects, where are they? They may not be in the SDK, but they must be available at run-time.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help you at compile time.  The work around are generally to make stubs in your project for the missing parts which will be rejected at load time (since they duplicate the real implementations) or to use reflection to hook up to the real ones at runtime.  It's not pretty.

Comment: Why can't I grab the run-time libs on my device and include them in my eclipse project? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Amongst other reasons, because the runtime jars contain not dalvik bytecode (instead of java byte code) but actually optimized dalvik bytecode, wheras you need a java jar for the initial stages of compilation before the conversion to dalvik in the sdk and optimized dalvik upon installation.  The general view is that those apps are supposed to eventually be re-written to use only SDK capabilities... but you know how priorities turn out in the real world.

Comment: Thanks Chris. In any case, I was able to hack out the functionality that I needed. The majority of errors were due to directly accessing super class member variables, which are only exposed via getters/setters in the SDK.